# Is there a way to read a text file using java but the text file has over 20 000 characters

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

I have i program that uses a text file to store the forenames of people but the problem is that when i use a BufferedReader, or a Scanner to read the file it does not work because there are too many characters in the text file (estimated about 20 000). And i know that BufferedReader has a limit of 8192 chars and Scanner has a limit of 1024 chars.

So what can i do to read all the characters without an error or some of them being left out?

```
BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("names.txt")));
```

(edit)

I found the problem it was not the BufferedReader it was the text file. The text file had become corrupted and so when i remade the text file and deleted the old one it worked. So thank you to everyone that tried to help me but i was just being an idiot.

Comment: It's not a limit, it's the size of the buffer. There's nothing left out, and if you had actually *tried* anything you would have noticed it.

Comment: I will get the code and post it but are you sure there is no limit

Comment: You might want to use `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("test.txt"), StaticCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Why would there be a limit? What would be the advantage of having a limit on the amount of characters you can read?

Comment: If you're actually having trouble reading more than 8k of data from a BuffereredReader, then you should [edit] your question to include your code which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. The default is large enough for most purposes.
in your case , 20,000 characters is not that much and the default buffer should be more than enough.